# bootstrap .tab('show') is not working from another method

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I am calling bootstrap tab from another function. I wonder why this works

```
if (!$('#' + sPagerName).find('a[href$="' + sTabName + '"]').parents("li").hasClass('active')){
  $('#' + sPagerName).find('a[href$="' + sTabName + '"]').trigger("click");
}
```

And this does not

```
$('#' + sPagerName)(' a[href="#' + sTabName + '"]').tab('show');
```

Is this the reason `.tab('show')` is not called from another function.

Comment: using angularjs , I am not changing url location

Comment: Where is `sPagerName` defined? What does it result to?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example